# Create a new personal page instance for each user

Tags: nodes, rules, users, redirection, path-aliases

I have a content type named 'personal' and a node (page) also called 'personal' which is of that content type.

I want my users to have their own private 'personal' page on my website where every user can post their own private stuff. Like a blog page where the page layout is the same for everyone but each user has their own posts on their profile page.

I am trying to achieve something like  www.mywebsite.com/personal/username (or www.mywebsite.com/username/personal)

I am using the Rules module but each user is still getting re-directed to the one and only 'personal' page I have created.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens when you visit `your-domain.com/user/USERNAME` ?

Comment: Use the technique described below by @fadehelix but combine it with [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

Answer (score 2):

### You can create new Views page like this:

[image]

Let me explain underlined options:

**Path: personal/%** - let you to create dynamic path. In addition "%" sign is a wildcard used by contextual filter;

**Relationships > Content:author** - this relationship is required by filters to show only nodes created by its author. Without this we would be able to filter only by user ID.

**Contextual Filters > User:name** - this is value of URL wildcard. It allow you to filter nodes by put any user name instead of % sign. 
For example: www.mywebsite.com/personal/john

**Filter Criteria > Current User (Yes)** - It shows only nodes created by current logged in user. Without this filter anyone can put any user name in url and see content created by this user.

Let me know if something is not clear to you.

Comment: thanks @fadehelix - however I am not getting the ' (author) user name ' option see screen below: http://imgur.com/JeIfoKU

Comment: Did you add relationship at first? Without this, as I mentioned, you only can set Author ID.

Comment: found it! - One more question: how do I attach the view I created to my personal page? I am confused as I thought this module replaced the need to use the personal page created using 'add content' button...